# How can prove that for all values of $a$, the range of the function $\sin(\frac{x}{a})+\cos(xa)$ will always lie between the interval $[-2,2]$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

*Question stated in the topic

What I tried to do:

Take the limit as $\lim_{a \to \infty}$, but I am not getting anywhere. :(

I think that limits must pop up somewhere as they are asking for all the values of $a$. But I do not know how to apply it to this function. Need help thanks!

Comment: "*limits must pop up somewhere*" $\;-\;$ Why? The problem is asking about a range. You don't need limits to know what the range of $\sin x$ is, for example.

Comment: Ask yourself first whats the range of $sin(x/a)$ and $cos(xa)$. Then how small or big can the values of $cos(xa)+ sin( x/a)$be ?

Comment: It is so trivial question, unless $x$ or $a$ are complex.

Comment: For $a=0$ the expression doesn't define a function, so it's not "for all values of $a$"

Comment: What's the smallest value of $$\sin(\text{it doesn't matter what appears here})  \text{?}  $$  How about the largest value?  Same two questions about cosine.

Comment: @Nightfly One should take care not to use "trivial" : it can be taken as very contemptuous to the person it is addressed. It is maybe "trivial" to you, but not necessarily for the student who asks this question, especially for this kind of question which is (voluntarily ?) misleading because the answer is so simple, indeed...

Comment: @dxiv I thought that limits would be needed because they stated "for all the values $a$", so I thought that they want me to take the limit to see what happens as $a$ gets bigger, that's why I stated(incorrectly now that I saw the solution) that "limits must pop up somewhere"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the comments already stated, the range of both $\sin$ and $\cos$ is $[-1, 1]$. Since we have
$$
-1 \leq \sin(x/a) \leq 1 \qquad\text{and}\qquad -1 \leq \cos(xa) \leq 1,
$$
we can add both inequalities giving
$$
-2 \leq \sin(x/a) + \cos(xa) \leq 2,
$$
thus the range is $[-2, 2]$.

A trickier question would be to prove that $f\colon \mathbb{R} \times (\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}) \to [-2, 2]$ with $f(x, a) = \sin(x/a) + \cos(xa)$ is surjective.

---

I don't know why you would think that, if there is *for all $a$*, then you have to take a limit. Limits just describe the behaviour of functions or series in very specific or extreme cases (e.g. $n \to \infty$ or $x \to 0^+$), often with the idea to describe something which can't be described with ordinary real numbers (think of what $1/\infty$ should be, maybe $\lim_{n\to\infty} 1/n$).

Comment: To me, it looked like they wanted to see what happens as $a$ gets bigger. Because they stated for all values of $a$, I got the hint that maybe they want me to take the limit for $a$

Comment: Obviously, I did not recognise that the answer was so simple(that was my fault) and ended up getting nowhere.

Comment: hmm,  playing around with the bonus question in my head.  Restricting to $a>0$ or $a<0$ gets us continuity,  so only need to show extremes can be hit.  Thus we need either $x/a=\pi / 2 + 2k\pi$ and $xa=2j\pi$ (or the obvious other case)  to have solutions for some some real $x, a$ and integers $k, j$.  hmm,  might play with this more